# Extract numbers from phone number input field (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, phone-number

I've got a phone number input field, which allows a user to add a phone number in whatever format they want (555-555-5555, (555) 555 - 5555, etc).

Since it a phone number field only, I can ignore everything but the numbers in the field.

I'm currently using the following code. *It extracts all the numbers, but the issue is that they are not in order - it's in a jumbled order.*

**How do I extract the numbers in the order that they appear in the original string?**

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $Phone, $matches);

$Phone = implode('', $matches[0]);
```

**Edit**: They are actually not in a jumbled order from this function - I was inserting the numbers into a int(10) database field, which caused the jumbling. But, the answers below are still a more efficient way of accomplishing my goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove any non-digits:

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^\d]/','',$Phone);
```

Note: '[^\d]' can be replaced with '\D' (safe in non-unicode mode).

Answer (score 2):

```
$Phone = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $Phone);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just replace everything in the string that is not a digit?

```
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $Phone);
```

Comment: What's the difference between the other examples using `^\d` and your `^0-9`?

Comment: None. \d is just an escape sequence that is the same as the character class [0-9].  Some escape sequences are dependent on the locale setting, but I don't believe \d is.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9\-]*$/",$Phone)) {
    echo "Only Numeric and strip (-)";
}
```

**Example:**

Good: `0877-9320-9356`

Failed: `0877 9320 9356` or `087793209356`